# Undo not working using a stack of 2D arrays

Tags: c#, console-application

So I have a working game of checkers (or draughts if you prefer), and i am trying to implement a simple undo feature.  I store my board in a 2D array and i am trying to use a stack to store the board before the player moves and if undo is selected the board is simply popped from the stack and redrawn.

here's my undo class

```
class Undo
{
    Stack<string[,]> prevMoves = new Stack<string[,]>();

    public Stack<string[,]> PrevMoves
    {
        get
        {
            return prevMoves;
        }
        set
        {
            prevMoves = value;
        }
    }

    public void AddCurrentBoardState(string[,] boardArray)
    {
        PrevMoves.Push(boardArray);
    }

    public string UndoMessage()
    {
        string choice;
        Console.WriteLine(" Press Enter to End your Turn or Press U to Undo");
        return choice = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    }

    public string[,] UndoMove()
    {
        return PrevMoves.Pop();
    }
```

before i do anything for the players turn i push the current array to the stack

```
Undo.AddCurrentBoardState(BoardArray);
```

then i move the player and draw the updated board

```
playerOne.Move(BoardArray, piece, move, playerOne);
PlayerOneMoveCount.countmoves();
Board.DrawBoard(BoardArray, PlayerOneMoveCount, PlayerTwoMoveCount);
```

I now try to implement my undo

```
string choice = Undo.UndoMessage();

if (choice == "U")
{
    BoardArray= Undo.UndoMove();
    Board.DrawBoard(BoardArray, PlayerOneMoveCount, PlayerTwoMoveCount);
}
```

When the bit above runs it prints the updated board after the player has moved not the original board that was pushed to the stack before the player move.

I have tried pulling the original board into a new 2D array but it still pulls the new updated board

```
if (choice == "U")
{
    string[,] originalBoard= new string[8, 10];
                originalBoard = Undo.UndoMove();
                Board.DrawBoard(originalBoard, PlayerOneMoveCount, PlayerTwoMoveCount);
}
```

Why does the new updated board keep getting printed?

PS I am not looking for someone to code a solution, this is coursework and I am just trying to understand the logic of why the same original board keeps getting printed instead of the one i pushed to the stack, its starting to give me a headache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is most likely your problem: `Undo.AddCurrentBoardState(BoardArray);`.

Think about what you are passing as argument here. Are you *really* passing the board state... or are you actually just passing *a reference* to your board state?

Read about [reference types here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-reference-type-parameters). Basically, you are currently saying, push the adress "x" of my state array to the stack. So unless you [copy your array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy(v=vs.110).aspx) before calling this function, you will just be pushing "x" over and over, so `Undo.UndoMove()` will return x.

When you try to mitigate your code here, you are doing some additional weird assignement stuff. I kind of see what you are trying to do, but my comments show what actually happens

```
// Create new array on adress y, store adress y in originalBoard
string[,] originalBoard= new string[8, 10]; 
// replace y inoriginalBoard with x from my stack, y is now lost forever
originalBoard = Undo.UndoMove();
```

To save your state, do something like this (untested)

```
// Create array on adress y
var currentState = new string[8, 10];
// Copy all contents of array on adress x to array on adress y
Array.Copy(BoardArray, currentState, 8 * 10)
// Save adress y on your undo stack
Undo.AddCurrentBoardState(currentState);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @Tewr  I hadn't considered i was only passing a reference.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else is interested, with Tewr's suggestion I managed to fix it by adding string[,] currentState = boardArray.Clone() as string[,];

Need to use Clone as copy doesn't work with 2d array's (well not as standard)

```
public void AddCurrentBoardState(string[,] boardArray)
    {
        string[,] currentState = boardArray.Clone() as string[,];
        PrevMoves.Push(currentState);
    }
```